# How to send multiple continuous values (i.e. video frames, signals) over socket programming using python

Tags: python, sockets

I am a newbie at python socket programming. I am trying to send video frames and two lists over the socket. But the problem is only one of the items is sent and the other one gets blocked. How can I send these two types of data simultaneously? Thank you for your help.

Server-side code:

```
import socket
import cv2, pickle,struct
import time
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
port=5050
host=socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    # now our endpoint knows about the OTHER endpoint.
    conn,add = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from {add} has been established.")
    msg=conn.recv(1024)
    print(msg)
    
    
    
    if conn:
        vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        X=[10,20,30]
        Y=[]
        for i in range(len(X)):
            y=X[i]*10
            Y.append(y)
        print(Y)
        X_data=pickle.dumps(X)
        Y_data=pickle.dumps(Y)
        conn.send(X_data)
        conn.send(Y_data)
        
        
        while(vid.isOpened()):
            img,frame = vid.read()
            a = pickle.dumps(frame)
            message = struct.pack("Q",len(a))+a
            conn.sendall(message)
           
            
            #cv2.imshow('TRANSMITTING VIDEO',frame)
            key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
            if key ==ord('q'):
                conn.close()
```

Client side Code: I haven't tried to use the lists in the client code. But if I send the lists first then the video portion does not work

```
import socket,pickle,struct
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
port=5050
host=socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
s.connect((host,port))

data=b""
payload_size = struct.calcsize("Q")
while True:
    msg=(bytes('Khan',"utf-8"))
    s.sendall(msg)
    
    while len(data) < payload_size:
        packet =s.recv(4*1024) # 4K
        if not packet: break
        data+=packet
    packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
    data = data[payload_size:]
    msg_size = struct.unpack("Q",packed_msg_size)[0]
    
    while len(data) < msg_size:
        data += s.recv(4*1024)
    frame_data = data[:msg_size]
    data  = data[msg_size:]
    frame = pickle.loads(frame_data)
    cv2.imshow("RECEIVING VIDEO",frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key  == ord('q'):
        break
s.close()
```

Comment: Your client code is expecting each message to be preceded by a length - but only the later video frames actually have the length preceding them, your two pickled arrays at the start of the connection don't.  So the first 8 bytes of the pickled data get misinterpreted as a length, which is likely to be *enormous* since you're using a 64-bit value, and the client loops forever trying to accumulate that much data.

Comment: So,can you please help me how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, you need to send one item and then clear/flush the socket buffer on the server-side before you send the next item.

Do this in a while loop and you can do it continuously forever.

I did it like this:

```
def clear_buffer(sock):
    try:
        while sock.recv(1024): pass
    except:
        pass

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("0.0.0.0",3389))
s.listen(10)
c,a = s.accept()
c.settimeout(1.0)
clear_buffer(c)
```

Comment: can you please explain it to me that what is c3 here

Comment: @AlmasrurKhan sorry. my bad. edited. do you understand now?

Comment: Thank you Deepak. I will try it and let you know

Comment: @AlmasrurKhan Sure